# Why isn't my INSERT IGNORE code NOT working?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to avoid inserting duplicates records into my table by using the PRIMARY KEY and  INSERT IGNORE methods. As suggested @ http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm

I added the PRIMARY KEY to the tables definition as shown below:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("flightSched") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE Alteration(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 

 timePeriod TIME default '00:00:00',
 depOrArriv VARCHAR(9),
 flightNo VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
 airline VARCHAR(20),
 dest VARCHAR(30),
 origin VARCHAR(30),
 depature VARCHAR(8),
 don VARCHAR(10),   
 arrivalTime VARCHAR(8),
 arrivalTimeSec VARCHAR(28),
 status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,

 image_type      varchar(25) not null default '',
 image           blob        not null,
 image_size      varchar(25) not null default '',
 image_name      varchar(50) not null default '',
PRIMARY KEY (id, flightNo, status)

)")
 or die(mysql_error());  

echo "Table Created!";
```

Find below the INSERT IGNORE code:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO Alteration 
                     (depOrArriv, flightNo, airline, origin, don, arrivalTime, arrivalTimeSec, status, image_type, image, image_size,                           image_name) 
                    VALUES('$depOrArriv', '$flightNo', '$airline', '$origin', '$don', '$arrivalTime', '$arrivalTime', '$status',                            '$image_type','$image', '$image_size', '$image_name' ) "); 
//                  or die(mysql_error());  

                    echo "Number of affected rows were: " . mysql_affected_rows();
```

While testing it I noticed that it STILL inserts duplicate records. 
Why is it still doing this? Can anyone help me point out what is wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Looking forward to your feedback.

Comment: Your `id` column is auto incrementing which means each row is effectively unique when it is used in your key

Comment: What do you mean 'duplicate'? Your `id` will be unique. Or is this about other 'duplicated' fields?

Comment: There wont be many duplicate primary keys in this composite key case where id is an auto increment

Comment: @Brendan Bullen the content in the e.g. VALUES ($depOrArriv,...) are all coming from HTML form. I don't want the end-user to insert records that already exist in the table. Most importantly NOT the flightNo, and status. The id just really increments per each inserted record and isn't helpful. Atleast I don't think so. Perhaps you could demonstrate how it could be used to avoid inserting duplicates?

Comment: @SirBT Please see my answer below - you can set a unique index on the FlightNo and status to prevent the duplicates from being inserted

Comment: @Alma Do Mundo I do NOT want the end-user to insert a row with duplicating fields/columbs "flightNo", "status". These should only appear once in the table. I hope I am clear... :-)

Comment: @Hanky 웃 Panky the KEY column's that should remain unique and not duplicated isnt id but rather "flightNo" and "status"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `id` column is auto incrementing which means each row is effectively unique when it is used in your key. You should inspect the data that you've inserted. You should see that each duplicate row actually has a separate and distinct `id`.

You can set a `UNIQUE` index on `flightNo` and `status` which would prevent the duplicate rows.

```
ALTER TABLE `Alteration` ADD UNIQUE (
    `flightNo` ,
    `status`
);
```

And then I would recommend just reducing your Primary Key to be `id`

**UPDATE**
As requested, this is a modified version of your code with a unique index used to prevent the duplicates:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("flightSched") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE Alteration(
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 timePeriod TIME default '00:00:00',
 depOrArriv VARCHAR(9),
 flightNo VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
 airline VARCHAR(20),
 dest VARCHAR(30),
 origin VARCHAR(30),
 depature VARCHAR(8),
 don VARCHAR(10),
 arrivalTime VARCHAR(8),
 arrivalTimeSec VARCHAR(28),
 status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 image_type varchar(25) not null default '',
 image blob not null,
 image_size varchar(25) not null default '',
 image_name varchar(50) not null default '',
 PRIMARY KEY (id),
 UNIQUE KEY `flightNo` (`flightNo`,`status`)
)") or die(mysql_error());

echo "Table Created!";

mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO Alteration (depOrArriv, flightNo, airline, origin, don, arrivalTime, arrivalTimeSec, status, image_type, image, image_size, image_name) VALUES('$depOrArriv', '$flightNo', '$airline', '$origin', '$don', '$arrivalTime', '$arrivalTime', '$status', '$image_type','$image', '$image_size', '$image_name' )");

echo "Number of affected rows were: " . mysql_affected_rows();
```

Comment: Thanks Brendan Bullen, but how do I also add the rest of the records such as $airline, $origin etc? sorry kind of a newbie to MySQL. ;-)

Comment: Once you've added the `UNIQUE` index, this will alter your table structure to allow the `INSERT IGNORE` statement you've written to work. Then you can execute it with all of the same variables as before but the index will prevent the duplicates for you.

Comment: do you mind kindly demonstrating what you mean in code? Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: @SirBT I've updated my answer with a modified version of your code. You will see that I've added a `UNIQUE KEY` to the table creation script (below the primary key).

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction. What I was really trying to do was to avoid inserting duplicates of the flightNo in the Alteration table, however update the other contents belonging to the same flightNo. I fixed this by removing the status from the table indexing definition. What I was left with is: UNIQUE KEY `flightNo` (`flightNo`). Also the mysql_query i use is REPLACE INTO Alteration. Now the rest of the table contents gets updated without adding flightNo duplicates. Cheers! I hope this helps other people. Cheers once again!

Comment: @SirBT Ah, that makes sense. Glad you figured it out. :)